# How to make EUDC to start effect without rebooting?

Tags: c, winapi, fonts

I want to Register some user defined character fonts programmatically. According to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317836%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I set up EUDC registry keys and values in my program. But the font does not start to effect. I have to reboot to make the character display correctly. When working with Private Character Editor, the modification made upon characters will start to effect immediately, so there must be some way to notify system to update font without rebooting. Any one knows how to 
achieve this?

By the way, I had tried broadcasting WM_FONTCHANGE message by the following code, but it seems not working...

```
SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_FONTCHANGE, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: Please upload code for your WM_FONTCHANGE message.

Comment: I added the code sending WM_FONTCHANGE message. But I don't think it will be usefull, since the program didn't recieve any WM_FONTCHANGE message when using Private Character Editor to modify the font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must use [EnableEUDC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162593%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Example:

```
EnableEUDC(FALSE);

// Your code for manipulating with registry

EnableEUDC(TRUE);
```

I not tested this, but **Eudcedit.exe** use similar technique.

Comment: Yes, I have found the document about EnableEUDC in MSDN, but there's no information about in which header file the prototype is decleared. The document sadi the function is defined in gdi32.lib,so I searched wingdi.h, but there's no such declearation. Could you tell me how to call this api? In the MSDN document, EnableEUDC is marked as legacy, is there any new api that has equivalent effect?

Comment: I use LoadLibrary to load gdi32.dll for calling EnableEUDC, and it works well. Thanks for Xearinox's answer. However I still wonder is there any new equivalent api, since EnableEUDC is marked legacy.